# AWS VPC Endpoint for S3 with Terraform - Error: multiple VPC Endpoint Services matched

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I'm using `aws_vpc_endpoint_service` in Terraform (v0.11.14) to create an AWS VPC Endpoint for S3 on my AWS account and recently started facing the following error: `Error: multiple VPC Endpoint Services matched; use additional constraints to reduce matches to a single VPC Endpoint Service`

The same code was working fine before. What's the resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution.

**Causes of the Issue:**

- AWS has just released a new feature in S3 (PrivateLink) which means that multiple results are now being returned when searching for the S3 endpoint service. Reference: [Amazon S3 now supports AWS PrivateLink](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/02/amazon-s3-now-supports-aws-privatelink/)
- Singular data sources in the Terraform AWS Provider (like aws_vpc_endpoint_service) return an error if multiple results are returned.

**Solution if AWS Provider Version >= v3.10.0:**

- Use the following in the Terraform template:

```
data "aws_vpc_endpoint_service" "s3" {
  service      = "s3"
  service_type = "Gateway"
}
```

**Solution if AWS Provider Version < v3.10.0:**

If you are unable to update to a recent version of the provider, as a temporary workaround you can also use com.amazonaws.REGION.s3 as an endpoint value in downstream configurations rather than using the datasource.

- Use the following in the Terraform template:

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id       = "${local.vpc_id}"
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.${data.aws_region.current.name}.s3"
}
```

That is all.

**Previous code for reference that is not working anymore:**

```
data "aws_vpc_endpoint_service" "s3" {
  service = "s3"
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id       = "${local.vpc_id}"
  service_name = "${data.aws_vpc_endpoint_service.s3.service_name}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For aws provider < v3.10.0 the problem could be solved using the `filter` configuration block in `aws_vpc_endpoint_service`

```
data "aws_vpc_endpoint_service" "s3" {
  service = "s3"
  filter {
    name   = "service-type"
    values = ["Gateway"]
  }
}
    
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id       = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  service_name = "${data.aws_vpc_endpoint_service.s3.service_name}"
}
```

See also github issue page https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17417